# Ok to implement backend/shared functionality for iPhone in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, iphone, cocoa

Is it ok to use the Webkit Javascript engine to implement cross-platform, non-GUI backend functionality on the iPhone, iPad?  In my case, I was interested in re-using Javascript code that I have that works on top of SQLite.  I thought I would need to re-implement the logic in Obj-C but perhaps I could just share it and expose some hooks into Obj-C using JSCocoa or straight through JavaScript core.  If I do this, is it ok to bypass the `UIWebView` control and go straight to JavaScriptCore or is that still considered a private framework?  I am still searching and will update this if I find the answer.

Comment: Questions like this make me very sad. Oh Apple, what have you done...

Comment: Matti, to answer: created one of the most profitable and powerful opportunities for developers ever.  Did developers ever make money on mobile before Apple.  Uhh, no.  Ok back to my question.

Comment: @John Wright: I take it their TOS now requires developers to post defensive comments about their draconian policies, lest their apps all mysteriously disappear and any iPhones in their possession explode?

Comment: @John Wright: Yeah, Steve Jobs sure is the creative genius of the century ¬__¬

Comment: Is it OK? Assuming you are talking about in relation to the updated SDK Agreement, probably. Is it going to be a good longterm solution? I don't know. It is quite possible that Apple could be wise to your "scheme" and reject your app for minimal functionality. Personally, I think you may be playing with fire.

Answer (score 1):

Although the iPhone uses WebKit, UIWebView does not expose it as a public interface.  To strictly follow apple guidelines, the only communication between a web page and the host application is by calling eval with stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString and by processing resource requests.

You can do a lot in javascript.  In fact, when it comes to controlling a UIWebView, javascript can often do more than Objective-C.  If your communications with the host application are simple enough you should be able to keep your existing code with minimal changes.

Comment: My interface with the host app would be fairly minimal but it seems silly to have to use a Webkit control.  Thanks for this good answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure it is legal, in fact I have done this recently for a project at my company. We had a GWT app which spat out a JavaScript/HTML application which we needed to be port to iPhone and Android. Rather than doing a complete rewrite on each platform, we went down the (slightly insane) route of keeping the Java/JavaScript backend and sticking on native code to handle the UI. Works well and you can't tell that in the background it is a browser that is running the show.